# Removing Toast from Action bar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm having action bar which display application Name, search and more action menu item, though i'm using sherlock library for that. I want to disable the toast of search and more item when i performing long press event in the action bar. Did anyone knows how to disable / redefine long press event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of the native action bar. It cannot be removed.